# Updating value of env:define when using images across multiple environments

Tags: docker

We are currently working on our build pipeline, which compiles our code and creates our cm/cd images, on SC managed cloud (sc 10.2). We have a single image for `cm` and `cd` that we deploy to all of our environments (`DEV`, `QA`,`UAT`, and `PRODUCTION`).

We'd like to update our environment app setting (`<add key="env:define" value="Local" />`) to reflect which environment the image has been deployed to, such as `nonproduction` for `QA`, `UAT`, and `DEV` and `Production` for our production site, so that we can use the setting in our rule-based configuration changes. We're not sure how you can do that per environment because of how images are created. Previously (before images), we would have created a transform that was triggered during the release pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I handle managing environment settings.

Assuming you start with a default `web.config` included with a vanilla instance, you can transform that during build with the appropriate key. In my case we decided to use the full word "environment" rather than the abbreviated form.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" key="environment:define" value=""/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Next you will want to add a new namespace to your configuration patches.

`xmlns:environment="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/environment/"`

**Example:** The following demonstrates the use of an **environment** namespace  where the possible values are "Dev", "Int", "Tst", "Prd".

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:environment="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/environment/">
  <sitecore environment:require="Dev or Int or Tst or Prd">
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Now, whether you are using standard VMs or containers you can override the environment variables with a key/value like the following:

`SITECORE_APPSETTINGS_ENVIRONMENT:DEFINE`
`Int`

[image: Sample]

Answer (score -1):

You need to use **XDT configuration transforms**. [Here you can find out the samples](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/developer-tools/applying-configuration-transforms.html) how to manage it in Docker for Sitecore solutions.

```
<appSettings>
   <add xdt:Transform="Insert" key="env:define" value="PROD"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Please provide a sample here from the link as well, as sometimes these links can be expired.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139039/discussion-on-answer-by-vadzim-papko-updating-value-of-envdefine-when-using-ima).